# Scheduled agents nsf and ntf

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Our products coded in Designer are usually structured as:

- database1.nsf,
- database2-production.nsf,
- database3-devel.nsf,

then, all of them use the same template:

- database-template-verX.X.ntf

Agents I code, are coded in NTF. After ntf is ready to be moved to NSF files, I usually just do Application > Refresh design. Everything works well. Now here is the thing...

When refreshing design and checking domino.log, usually newly created agents work great on:

- database1.nsf,
- database3-devel.nsf

However,
- database2-production.nsf doesn't seem to get agents properly. Even If I open NSF file directly in Designer, everything looks good. The agents just don't run. All agents are ENABLED, have proper permissions and are signed. That -production.nsf database just doesnt want to cooperate.

Usually we solve this with restarting domino and even then, sometimes we arent sure if agent will start running as scheduled or not.

Did someone else had similar problems or maybe knows what is wrong? It looks like there's some kind of cache or something..

We have no idea...

Any help would be great!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1) database property: 'disable background agents for this database'?
2) are all databases u mentioned are located on same server?
3) try to fix/compact database

Comment: Does database2-produciton.nsf have the same replica ID of any of the other databases?

Comment: Hi. 

@dmytro: 1) all 3 of the databases have setting for disabling background agents disabled- unticked; 2) all 3 databases are on same server, all 3 are backed up by PULL ONLY set server2. 3) did that too, didn't helped either.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz: I've just checked replica ID's from all 3 databases. They all have unique replica ID.

Comment: @gregor: then try to run fix/compact or even re-create it.

Comment: The "sometimes it runs and sometimes it doesn't" indicates to me that it is likely a server problem. You don't mention whether there are any messages in the server log or if the agent log in that database shows anything (I assume that it says "This agent has never been run before", but need to ask). Are there problems with memory, disk space, agent run times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tell amgr debug *` to have the agent manager output detailed information to the console.  Unfortunately, if it seems that restarting the server solves the problem temporarily, you may have to collect debug information over a long period of time to see a before and after picture of what's going on -- and even then it might not point you toward the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Check all the design elements property, Prohibit Design refresh or replace to modify should not be checked. Also check your acl for this database.